# Virtual method can be used in derived class

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Is it possible to write virtual method in derived class and invoking a parent class which has a override method. I was asked in an interview , I gave ans that it will give error because virtual can be declared in parent/base class not in derived class

namespace Polymorphism
{
    public class parent
    {
        public virtual void print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("parent class");
        }
    }

```
public class derive : parent
{
    public override void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived Class");
    }
}

public class ddd : derive
{
    public override void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("invoke DDDDd");
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        parent p = new derive();
       // p = new ddd();
        p.print();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you give a basic example demonstrating the concept you have a question about please?

Comment: Please reword your question with more clarification and if possible provide sample code.

Comment: i have provided the code